# OrTools MIP solver copy: pywraplp.Solver copy()

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

In Or-tools, how can I deep-copy a Solver object?

Alternatively, how can I duplicate the content of a constraint?

I want to copy a solver object and in the copy, add a variable to each constraint.

```py
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

def create_constraints(model):
    x = model.NumVar(0, 1, 'x')
    y = model.NumVar(0, 1, 'y')
    constraint = model.Constraint(-pywraplp.Solver.infinity(), 1)
    constraint.SetCoefficient(x, 1)
    constraint.SetCoefficient(y, 1)
    return constraint

# Create the first solver and add constraints
solver1 = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')
constraint1 = create_constraints(solver1)

# Create the second solver
new_solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')

# copy vars... kinda ok
for var in solver.variables():
    new_solver.NumVar(lb=var.Lb(), ub=var.Ub(), name=var.name())

# I want to copy the constraints, but adding a new var to each one
slacks = list()
for i, cst in enumerate(solver.constraints()):
    sl = new_solver.NumVar(0, 1e20, 'Slack{}'.format(i))
    new_solver.Add(cst + sl)  # this line fails
    slacks.append(sl)

new_solver.Minimize(new_solver.Sum(slacks))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with pywraplp, and it is in maintenance mode.

I have just added support for model deep cloning and with model_builder (ortools.linear_solver.python.model_builder). This will be released in or-tools 9.8 (normally out this week or next).

Here is the example that demonstrates cloning:

```
    print("Cloning the model.")
    model_copy = model.clone()
    x_copy = model_copy.var_from_index(x.index)
    y_copy = model_copy.var_from_index(y.index)
    z_copy = model_copy.new_bool_var("z")
    c2_copy = model_copy.linear_constraint_from_index(c2.index)
```

found in the complete [example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/main/ortools/linear_solver/samples/clone_model_mb.py).